# trying to update or insert records into an external excel worksheet using SQL query

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to insert or update an external worksheet using SQL with VBA. Below the full function code.
The error happen when I try to open the recordset within the loop passing the sql select query.
Any help would be appreciated. I know that the connection string works as I am using it on other code.

The SQL string looks like this:

```
select top 1 VALUENAME FROM [TradingTotals$] WHERE LOWER(VALUENAME)= LOWER('Trading') AND VALUEDATE =29/05/2020 AND CLOSINGMONTH = 'May' ORDER BY VALUEDATE DESC)
```

Full Function code

```
Public Function InsertClosingMonthTotals(ByVal CollOfTradeLogTotObj As Collection) As Boolean 

   Dim IsSuccess As Boolean
   Dim Item As TradeLogTotalsObj
   Dim Sql As String
   Dim SqlSelect As String
   Dim ConnDbString As String

   Dim TotalRecords As Long

   Dim Name As String
   Dim Value As Variant
   Dim Trading As Variant
   Dim LongShort As Variant
   Dim Therms As Variant
   Dim Valdate As Date
   Dim ClosingMonth As String

   ClosingMonth = Helper.FormatValue(Date, formatTypes.AsMonthlongOnly)


   Set Glob_Conn = New ADODB.Connection
   Set Glob_RecSet = New ADODB.Recordset

   ' Client-side cursor for correct return of record count
   Glob_RecSet.CursorLocation = adUseClient

   'Get Connection string according to the database server type
   ConnDbString = Helper.GetConnectionString(ServerTypes.Excel, Glob_FilePathForDataInput)


   'if the connection is closed then open it
   If (Glob_Conn.State = 0) Then
      Glob_Conn.Open (ConnDbString)
   End If


   For Each Item In CollOfTradeLogTotObj
      Name = Item.Name
      Value = Helper.FormatValue(Item.Value, AsNumber)
      LongShort = Helper.FormatValue(Item.LongShort, AsDecimalThreeDigits)
      Therms = Helper.FormatValue(Item.Therms, AsDecimalThreeDigits)
      Valdate = Helper.FormatValue(Item.dateTime, AsDateDisplay)

      SqlSelect = "select top 1 VALUENAME FROM [" & Glob_SheetNameTotalBooks & "$]" & _
      " WHERE LOWER(VALUENAME)= LOWER(" & "'" & Name & "'" & ")" & " AND VALUEDATE =" & Valdate & _
      " AND CLOSINGMONTH = " & "'" & ClosingMonth & "'" & _
      " ORDER BY VALUEDATE DESC)"

      Debug.Print ("SQL SELECT " & SqlSelect)
      Debug.Print ("*************************************************************")

      'open the record set
      If (Glob_RecSet.State <> 1) Then
     ' ******* ERROR ON LINE BELOW ON OPEN **********
      Glob_RecSet.Open SqlSelect, Glob_Conn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockOptimistic
      End If

      TotalRecords = Glob_RecSet.RecordCount
      If (TotalRecords > 0) Then
      Sql = "UPDATE TradingTotals SET VALUENAME =" & "'" & Name & "'" & _
      ",VALUEDATE =" & Valdate & _
      ",VALUE =" & Value & _
      ",LONGSHORT =" & LongShort & _
      ",THERMS =" & Therms & _
      ",CLOSINGMONTH =" & "'" & ClosingMonth & "'" & _
      "  WHERE LOWER(VALUENAME) = LOWER(" & Name & ") AND VALUEDATE = " & Valdate & " AND CLOSINGMONTH =" & ClosingMonth
      Else
      Sql = "INSERT INTO " & Glob_SheetNameTotalBooks & " (VALUENAME,VALUEDATE,VALUE, LONGSHORT, THERMS, CLOSINGMONTH )" & _
      " VALUES (" & "'" & Name & "'" & "," & Valdate & "," & Value & "," & LongShort & "," & Therms & "," & ClosingMonth & ")"
      End If



      Debug.Print ("SQL INSERT " & Sql)
      Debug.Print ("*************************************************************")

      Glob_Conn.Execute Sql

   Next Item

 'cleanup
   Helper.CloseConnectionObjects Glob_RecSet, Glob_Conn

   InsertClosingMonthTotals = IsSuccess
End Function
```

[image]

**EDIT**
this query works

```
SQL SELECT select TOP 1 VALUENAME FROM [TradingTotals$] WHERE LOWER(VALUENAME) ='Trading'
```

and seems that the issue is with LOWER() ; does anyone know if LOWER() cannot be used in excel queries?

**EDIT 2**

it seems that is just a matter of "properly" writing the query in Excel; this one below works. In the previous one tehre also was an extra ")" at the end of teh query

```
SQL SELECT select top 1 VALUENAME FROM [TradingTotals$] WHERE VALUENAME= 'Trading' AND VALUEDATE ='29/05/2020' AND CLOSINGMONTH = 'May' ORDER BY VALUEDATE DESC
```

I am trying now to use LOWER() again

**EDIT 3**
LOWER() dos not work, at least in the way I am using  it in VBA;

```
SQL SELECT select top 1 VALUENAME FROM [TradingTotals$] WHERE LOWER(VALUENAME)='Trading' And ValueDate =  '29/05/2020' AND CLOSINGMONTH = 'May' ORDER BY VALUEDATE DESC
```

I also tried double quotes for literals

Comment: What's the `$` for at the end of `Glob_SheetNameTotalBooks`  in the query - is that a SQL thing?

Comment: Also you have an unnecessary `)` at the end of the query: `ORDER BY VALUEDATE DESC)`

Comment: In other words I think the reason it's failing is simply because the query isn't valid.

Comment: also, I think JET SQL uses double quotes to denote string literals

Comment: Sorry but I am writing this in VBA and in order to query a Spreadsheet you do need the $ at the end

Comment: @ jamheadart you are right

Comment: @ArcheBird I did tried using double quotes but no joy

Comment: shouldn't that be LCASE() instead of LOWER()?

Comment: LCASE() in SQL ? Ok I'll give it a try

Comment: I was confusing SQL and SQL server syntax ? LCASE works perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So at the end there were different issues but mostly due with incorrect query syntax as I am writing SQL as when querying SQL server; not yet up to speed with excel query syntax.

Thanks to all who added useful comments, I am unaware on how to accept an answer from a comment so I am posting this as an answer but no credit to me at all; all credit to the great folks that added comments here.

I am now facing other issues with the insert.. basically even if I pass numbers as long and dates it get stored in excel as general. Even if I format the columns in the spreadsheet as date and number, it get reverted again to general?? but I am opening a new question for this issue